# Is there an MMO-related research body?

Tags: mmo

I'm trying to find a research resource for MMOs -- preferrably where people send papers to be published, have conferences, etc. If nothing else, just a repository of articles would be nice. Is there a site like that? I'm assuming it would be a subconference of a bigger group.

Comment: -1 For a complete lack of specifics in what information is being sought, beyond that it should have something to do with MMOs.  Are you looking for psychological effects?  Social?  Cultural?  Economic?  Historic perspectives?  Game-mechanical?  Of what level, and for what purpose?

Comment: As with most conferences, there is a main general topic. If it was somehow unclear I'm looking for any aspect in relation to computer science. Just as you would go to a conference on the broad context of web services which encompasses hundreds of possible sub topics. I am asking if there is a general body of research or even just specific ones on MMOs. If there were a conference specific to this type of game development it would certainly contain a large range of topics. Hence the request for any knowledge of such a resource.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such a thing does not really exist; games are not a very established subject in academia (except for graphics, although there is a [trend towards that changing](http://www.etc.cmu.edu/site/), perhaps) and what "research" is done that specifically pertains to the MMO field is likely done internally by studios developing them and thus would probably be considered a trade secret and kept undisclosed.

Your best bet is probably the [LOGIN conference](http://www.loginconference.com/).

Comment: I know there are hundreds of published papers on graphics, AI specific to games, massive user management, etc. While there won't necessarily be a ACM conference dedicated explicitly to it, I would say there must be a good resource. That being said, LOGIC seems like a great start for me to look into, if I can just find some publications from it.

Comment: There are probably papers published that are relevant to MMOs (economics, networking, et cetera) but (as far as I know) you won't find them collected anywhere outside the usual places -- ACM, and all that, which I assume you're already familiar with.

Comment: Well I suppose I'll go through the ACM archives to see what there is a little more thoroughly.

Comment: First link is a 404, the second just keeps loading…

Comment: The first one loads for me still (it's the Entertainment & Technology Center at Carnegie Mellon, which may help somebody find it through other means). The second link does appear dead. I thought the conference itself had gone out of business but I guess it's still alive on Twitter (@loginconference)? Not sure.